# Call a UserControl method from another UserControl

Tags: wpf, methods, call

I am trying to call a method from a UserControl from a different UserControl. I am not able to trace the UserControl i am trying to call the method from to call the method.

I am trying to call the following method that is in AddDeal.xaml.cs

```
        public void loadDealProducts()
        {
            InfoBox.Information("loadDealProducts called.", "testing");
        }
```

I am tracing the AddDeal UserControl and trying to call the method loadDealProducts() in file AddDealProducts.xaml.cs using the following method

```
            Window window = null;
            if (sender is Window)
                window = (Window)sender;
            if (window == null)
                window = Window.GetWindow(sender);
            return window;

          (window as AddDeal).loadDealProducts();
```

But window is returning null so i can't call the method loadDealProducts.

Instead of getting a Window using GetWindow, is there a way of getting the UserControl? I tried Window.GetUserControl and UserControl.GetUserControl but there is no such method.

sender is the DependencyObject from AddDeal.xaml.cs which i get when i click a button on AddDeal.xaml as following:

```
<Button Click="BtnAddProducts" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ProductID}">Add Product</Button>
```

which calls the following:

```
        private void BtnAddProducts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender as DependencyObject;
            Window AddProductsDialog = new Window {
                Title = "Add Products to Deal",
                Content = new AddDealProduct(button, productID, false, 0)
            };
            AddProductsDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
```

As you can see i am sending `button` which is a DependencyObject on AddDeal.xaml.cs/xaml

When it opens a new window AddDealProduct, it has AddDealProduct.xaml (UI file) and its .xaml.cs code-behind file. In this file i want to call a function from the calling UserControl(AddDeal).

Comment: Where do you create an instance of `AddDeal`? In what window? And where is `AddDealProducts` located?

Comment: I have two files, AddDeal.xaml and AddDealProducts.xaml and both files have a xaml.cs code-behid file where i do the c# coding. Both files have <UserControl x:Class="AddDeal">...UI Elements and styles....</UserControl>  in the .xaml files.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain more.

Comment: Since your whole window is going to be that usercontrol, I think it should be a window instead of a usercontrol. When you are casting sender this presumably from a click or some such event. (Some guesswork is necessary here because you haven't explained enough). Sender is (probably) going to be a button rather than a window. You'd have to cast the sender to whatever that is, then getwindow on that. If sender is in the usercontrol you want then....Get the content of the window in order to find your usercontrol.

Comment: You are along the right lines, i have to get the UserControl but it is a function i want to call that is in the UserControl class/file.

Comment: I tried to change the tags for UserControl to Window in AddDeal.xaml.cs and AddDeal.xaml but i get the following error when i try to display it in a Dialog Wndow;
```System.InvalidOperationException: 'Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.'```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it.

I am sending a `DependencyObject sender` that i get from `Button Click`  event from source Window UserControl, to another UserControl class, as a parameter.

Then i use the sender object to resolve a UserControl and call a function in its class from a different UserControl class.

To call the function i do the following:

```
AddDealUserControl ownerx2 = FindVisualParent<AddDealUserControl>(sender);
ownerx2.loadDealProducts();
```

FindVisualParent helper class:

```
        public static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
     where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // get parent item
            DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

            // we’ve reached the end of the tree
            if (parentObject == null) return null;

            // check if the parent matches the type we’re looking for
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                return parent;
            }
            else
            {
                // use recursion to proceed with next level
                return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.